# How to map a 64 bits value in restkit

Tags: ios, restkit

My Json response is returning a 64 bits value.
I need to map this 64 bits value to my iOS model.

How to do the mapping ? I was initially using a NSInteger type but it is only 32bits.

If I'm using a int64_t in my iOS model, the mapping is not done by restkit.

How to fix my issue ?
Is it possible to define our own mapping in Restkit ?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to make sure is that your property is of type NSNumber, then after the object mapping you can extract what you need with `-(NSInteger)longLongValue` method.

Comment: A long on iOS is 32bit wide, not 64 (at least for the current 32bit releases of iOS)